# How to make Google endpoints secure with private and public key pair?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-endpoints, private-key

I generated `Endpoints` for `Android` and need to make them secure using `private/public` key pair. 
Any reference on it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read this ? : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

But I recommend to you to use oauth2 authentication with login/password Google with the button Google Sign-In: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

Be carefull, on Android project, you can't store anything because it's too  easy to decompile an Android apk and get back private information.. (Like your private key)

Comment: Just a note, your public key is by definition not private information. Maybe you meant private key.

Comment: Oh yes ! Sorry I'm an absent minded..